# Ireland Egypt visa appointment missing documents after appointment

Tags: ireland, embassies, dublin, cairo

After my appointment and a 4 hour drive back and I hold a critical permit and my first time to Dublin I had forgot about a UK refusal 5 years ago.

Is there any way I could retrieve the reason as an Egyptian with no UK address? And how can I try to submit within papers not to be understood as fraud before it’s submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a ‘subject access request’ to obtain personal information about you that is held on the Home Office’s immigration records. You will receive a response within 30 days of your identity being verified by the Home Office. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration

AFAIK, if you’ve already attended your biometric appointment and submitted your supporting papers, the only way you can try to correct your error is to withdraw the application and re-submit.